# Why do we use the Java virtual machine?

Tags: java, c++, assembly, virtual-machine, processor

I am trying to wrap my head around the Java Virtual Machine and why it uses bytecode.  I know it has been asked so many times, but somehow I couldn't finally make the correct assumption, so I researched many things and decided to explain how I think it works and if it's correct.

I understand that in C++, compiler compiles the source code on the specific (architecture + operating system). So, compiled version of C++ for (x86 + Windows) won't run on any other architecture or operating system.

### My assumptions

When Java compiler compiles the source code into bytecode, It doesn't do the compilation depending on architecture or operating system. The source code will always be compiled to the **same** bytecode if it's compiled on Windows or Mac. Let's say we compiled and now, send the bytecode to another computer (x86 + windows). In order for that computer to run this bytecode, It needs JVM. Now, JVM knows what architecture + operating system it's running on. (x86 + windows). So, JVM will compile bytecode to x86 + Windows and it will produce machine code which can be run by the actual computer now.

So, even though we use Java Virtual Machine, we still run the actual machine code on our operating system and not on the virtual machine. Virtual Machine just helps us to transform bytecode into machine code.

This means that when using Java, the only thing we have to worry about is installing JVM and that's it.

I just always thought that the Virtual Machine is just a computer itself where it would run the code in its own isolated place, but in case of JVM, i don't think that's correct, because I think machine code JVM produces still has to be run on the actual operating system we have.

**Do you think my assumptions are correct?**

Comment: Depending on some heuristics, (how often a block of code is executed and so on), that same code will be compiled at run time by the JIT compiler. So that assembly generated is tightly couple with the underneath architecture.

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you think what I said is correct or I am wrong ?

Comment: "JVM will compile bytecode to x86 + windows and it will produce machine code which can be run by the actual computer now." - That's not how it works in principle. The VM interprets the bytecode, it doesn't produce an executable and run that. (In practice, JIT does do runtime bytecode to native code compilation, but I believe usually only for "hot" parts of the code.)

Comment: "So, JVM will compile bytecode to x86 + windows and it will produce machine code which can be run by the actual computer now." As far as I know this part is not accurate, otherwise it would definite the purpose, the bytecode is the same, but the generate assembly will be different (naturally).

Comment: JIT compiler is still in java virtual machine.  So, let's say that it's  still JVM which compiles the bytecode to machine code.

Comment: Here is a blog on the subject which I find easy to read and digest: [understand-jvm-and-jit-compiler](https://julio-falbo.medium.com/understand-jvm-and-jit-compiler-part-1-a94c27d32478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When Java compiler compiles the source code into bytecode, It doesn't do the compilation depending on architecture or operating system. The source code will always be compiled to the same bytecode if it's compiled on Windows or Mac.

All correct.

> Let's say we compiled and now, send the bytecode to another computer (x86 + windows). In order for that computer to run this bytecode, It needs JVM. Now, JVM knows what architecture + operating system it's running on. (x86 + windows). So, JVM will compile bytecode to x86 + windows and it will produce machine code which can be run by the actual computer now.

This is mostly correct, but there are a couple things that are a bit "off"

First of all, to execute the bytecodes on **any** computer you need a JVM.  That includes the computer on which you compiled the bytecodes.

(It is *theoretically* possible that a computer could be designed and implemented to execute the JVM bytecode instruction set as its native instruction set.  But I don't know if anyone has ever seriously contemplated doing this.  It would be pointless.  Performance would not be comparable with hardware that you can by for a couple of hundred dollars.  The JVM bytecode instruction set is designed to be compact and simple, and it is relatively easy to JIT compile.  Not to be executed efficiently.)

Secondly a typical JVM actually operates in two modes:

- It starts out executing the bytecodes in software using an interpreter.
- After a bit, it selectively compiles bytecodes of heavily used methods to the platform's native instruction set and executes the native code.  The compilation is done using a JIT compiler.

Note that the JIT compiler is platform specific.

> So, even though, we use Java Virtual Machine, we still run the actual machine code on our operating system and not on the virtual machine.

That is correct.

> *[The Java]* Virtual Machine just helps us to transform bytecode into machine code.

The JVM actually does a lot more.  Things like:

- Garbage collection
- Bytecode loading and verification
- Implementing reflection
- Providing native code methods for bridging between Java classes and operating system functionality
- Implementing infrastructure for monitoring, profiling, debugging and so on.

> This means that when using Java, the only thing we have to worry about is installing JVM and that's it.

Yes.  But in a modern JDK there are other alternatives; e.g. `jlink` will generate an executable that has a cut-down JRE embedded in it so that you don't need to install a JRE.  And GraalVM supports ahead of time (AOT) compilation.

> I just always thought that the Virtual Machine is just a computer itself where it would run the code in its own isolated place, but in case of JVM, i don't think that's correct, because I think machine code JVM produces still has to be run on the actual operating system we have.

Ah yes.

The term "virtual machine" has multiple meanings:

- A Java Virtual Machine "executes" Java bytecode ... in the sense above.
- A Linux or Windows virtual machine is where the user's application and the guest operating system are running under the control of a "hypervisor" operating system.  The applications and guest OS use the native hardware to execute instructions, but they don't have full control of the hardware.
- And there are potentially other shades of meaning.

If you conflate JVMs with other kinds of virtual machine, you can get yourself in knots.  Don't.  They are different enough that conflating the concepts in not going to help you understand.

Comment: wohoooo, That's the answer I'd not think about getting. Thanks so much Stephen. you made my day ! ! !

Comment: "it selectively compiles bytecodes of heavily used methods" I might be wrong but even if the method is not executed that often but it contains a loop (hot spot) with heavy computation it will also compile it

Comment: @dreamcrash - Yes.  Utilization is determined by "self-profiling", so a method with loops that are executed intensively will be JIT compiled.  Indeed, the JVM is able to switch to running a method's JIT compiled code while a call to the method is running.  Clever stuff.

Comment: Depending on how strict you are about "native", there's always Jazelle.

Comment: Hmm ... yes.  I wasn't aware of that.  And I also recall there was a Sun project in the 1990's to build a native Java machine.

Comment: Re: a JVM vs. something like VirtualBox: the key difference is what kind of guest machine is being virtualized.  For VirtualBox, the guest is an x86 PC.  For a JVM, it's a Java machine, which is only ever intended to exist virtually.  When the guest uses the same instruction-set as the host, then with some hardware support (e.g. Intel VT-x or AMD-V) the VM can let guest machine code be executed by the real CPU.  If not, e.g. emulating an x86 PC on an ARM Mac, then the situation is a lot closer to what JVMs do: you can interpret or JIT.  (ping  @GiorgiLagidze)

Answer (score 5):

When compiling java code, java-bytecode is created.

This bytecode is platform independent and can be run by the JVM. This means that other programming languages like [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) can also generate this java-bytecode and target the JVM.

So you are correct about the java-bytecode being the same for every platform.

Where you aren't entirely correct however is, that the JVM converts the java-bytecode to native bytecode.

The JVM executes the java-bytecode instead and gives the instructions to the operating system. While executing, the JVM compiles bunches of java-bytecode to native code, which the operating system can then execute. This happens while the code is executed so a class that is never loaded will also never be executed and will never end up as machine code.

Due to this we can use features like [Reflection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-java/) where some of the java-bytecode of a class files can be modified at runtime before being compiled to native machine code.

The JVM basically sits between the operating system and the java-bytecode. In some sense just like a normal VM.

The article below has a nice visualization of the JVM.

https://www.guru99.com/java-virtual-machine-jvm.html

Comment: If JVM executes the java-bytecode, how do we get machine code ?

Comment: The JVM executes the code. When the java-bytecode tells the JVM to open a file, the JVM executes this on the operating system, handling the differences between the operating systems for you. The JVM basically gives commands from the java-bytecode to the operating system acting as a middleman. (this is a very simplified explanation)

Comment: It is more complicated than that.  In most modern JVMs, there is a JIT compiler that compiles bytecodes to native code.

Comment: I think I got it. So, JVM executes the bytecode. If the bytecode is so small and says `int x = 5+5`,  JVM translates this instruction for the actual architecture + operating system that JVM is running on. correct ?

Comment: @StephenC yes, that's what I said.  I don't know why some people say it just executes and that's it.  Here we can see https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/java.jpg

Comment: Yes Giorgi, it is what you said.  It is not what this answer says though.

Comment: @StephenC by any chance, have you read my actual question ? do you agree with me on all that ?

Comment: Yes I did.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The java byte code is a form of intermediate code.

That code can be *interpreted*, a JVM is such an **interpreter** emulating (simulating) every single byte code instruction. This is slow but easily portable.

That code can be *compiled* to native code, normally a JVM contains a just-in-time **compiler** for code that is indeed executed. This native code can be optimized for the current machine it is running on, and the native code does not need to be loaded from file, and code inlining can be done.

So the JVM principly is a turbo-charged *interpreter*, of java byte code, portable to many platforms.

*Context:*

- [Other languages] Microsoft's C# language is more of a *compiler*.
- [Other intermediate codes] LLVM IR is an intermediate code from the C side, compilable.
- [Other JVMs] There are more than one JVM, with different techniques.

Comment: Thanks Joop for answering. By reading your answer, it makes me believe that I was somehow correct.

Comment: Yes, java came from a notorious slow interpreter (run in browser) to a really fast language environment with some compilation. swift-lynx is correct too in objecting that the JVM is basically an interpreter.

Comment: yes, but i think,  now JVM produces machine code which runs on the actual operating system, but that kind of detail is not that interesting at all. Joop - one question though - so we can presume that Java virtual machine is a very different kind of virtual machine than the one such as oracle virtualbox for example right ? because JVM produces machine code which gets run not on the VM, but on the actual operating system. In case of virtualbox, everything runs on the isolated machine (even the instructions and everything). what do you think ?

Comment: Totally different things, those virtual machines emulate firmware, the hard machine. Still: a JVM interpreter loads a class as data, and then emulates a Java CPU, loading an "instruction", and calling an emulation of that instruction (to be clear).